# Compilation error while running scala.swing._

Tags: java, scala, swing, intellij-idea

I am new to scala and practicing to make a GUI. I have used the following code:

```
import scala.swing._

class UI extends MainFrame {
  title = "GUI Program #1"
  preferredSize = new Dimension(320, 240)
  contents = new Label("Here is the contents!")
}

object GuiProgramOne {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val ui = new UI
    ui.visible = true
    println("End of main function")
  }
}
```

and also installed the swing library in build sbt as:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.10.2"
```

and there are exceptions that i see:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Proxy$class
    at scala.swing.Window.<init>(Window.scala:25)
    at scala.swing.Frame.<init>(RichWindow.scala:75)
    at scala.swing.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.scala:19)
    at UI.<init>(GuiProgramOne.scala:3)
    at GuiProgramOne$.main(GuiProgramOne.scala:11)
    at GuiProgramOne.main(GuiProgramOne.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Proxy$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

I am really getting confused. Can someone guide me? Thanks

I am studying this stuff from:

```
http://otfried.org/scala/index_28.html
```

Comment: Did you try to run a simple Hello World example without swing? I think it's a class path problem that has nothing to do with swing...

Comment: I already tried that. Can you tell me how to add path or how should I resolve it

Comment: did you follow your tutorial at http://otfried.org/scala/install.html and http://otfried.org/scala/compiling.html ? I think the class files have to be in the right folder or jar. how do you run your code?

Comment: I am running in IntelliJ.

Comment: Please read the docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html